# when i apply update query to table its update all my data not slected once

Tags: c#

when i apply this query its updates all the data, rather then updating the records against the selected grpid. grpID is auto genetrated grpID column, the remaining coloumns are

> stdrno, stdnames, session, disipline, cntno, email

```
private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "update tbl_grp set Stdrno='" + stdrnoTextBox.Text + "',Stdnames='" + stdnamesTextBox.Text + "',Disipline='" + disiplineComboBox.Text + "',Session='" + sessionTextBox.Text + "',Cntno='" + cntnoTextBox.Text + "',Email='" + emailTextBox.Text + "' where GrpID= ''";
            SqlCommand comand = new SqlCommand(query, connn);

        SqlDataReader datareader;

        try
        {
            connn.Open();
            datareader = comand.ExecuteReader();

            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated!", "Updation Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

            while (datareader.Read())
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: your question is not clear to answer

Comment: you are not providing any grpid in the where clause, how can it updates all the data. would you please show where are you specifying the grpid? in the sample provided it is just empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, please never ever again concat sql parameters and here is [WHY](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). Instead use parameterized queries as in the example below. Second, it seems like you forgot to set value for `GrpID` filter, however in this case none of the entities should have been updated.

```
const string sqlUpdateQuery = @"
        UPDATE 
            tbl_grp 
        SET Stdrno = @stdrno
            Stdnames = @stdnames 
            ...
        WHERE GrpID = @grpid
";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sqlUpdateQuery, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("stdrno", stdrnoTextBox.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("stdnames", stdnamesTextBox.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("grpid", grpidVariable);
        // ... //

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```